# Should i nullify an interrupted thread?

Tags: java

I created a thread like this:

```
private Thread t = new Thread() {
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        while(true) {
        // do work
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    }
}
};
t.start();
```

Then i interrupted it using `t.interrupt()`.

As soon the thread stops and get on sleep() it will interrupt and become unusable, but will it stay on memory?

Do i have to call `t = null`, or the GC will take care of that?

I'm trying to dynamically interrupt the thread and recreate it when needed (using `t = new Thread()`), but im not sure if just interrupt() removes the old thread from memory. I've searched but couldn't find this specfic answer.

Comment: `interrupt()` only tells the thread that he has been interrupted, no "black magic" behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Thread class is a proxy for the OS Thread.  Before you call start() there is no actual OS thread and after the thread stops it is cleaned up even if you hold on to the Thread object.  At this point it just like any other object and it will be cleaned up in the normal way.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are using this code snippet inside a method thus Thread t becomes local variable and it will be cleared by gc , just make sure you don't use this reference variable further down in the method.